# Onclick function

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have already searched on google, on the forum there is nobody in the same case as me,

I explain everything:

http://prntscr.com/dgpd3v

http://prntscr.com/dgpd9d

Code source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>cc</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="<a href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" rel="nofollow">https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js</a>" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form target="id.php" method="post">
<button name="purchase" onclick="purchase('19d9309b6091', 'eth');">ETH</button>
<button name="purchase" onclick="purchase('19d9309b6091', 'btc');">BTC</button>
<button name="purchase" onclick="purchase('19d9309b6091', 'paypal');">Paypal</button>
<button name="purchase" onclick="purchase('19d9309b6091', 'pm');">Perfect Money</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function purchase(productId, paymentMethod) {
        let coupon = $('#coupon').val();
        $('#purchaseContainer').hide();
        $('#purchaseContainerError').text('').hide();
        $.post('', {
            purchase: "1",
            paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
            productId: productId,
            coupon: coupon
        }).done(function(data) {
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(json) if (json.error) {
                $('#purchaseContainer').show();
                $('#purchaseContainerError').text(json.error).show();
                return;
            } else {
                if (json.urlToRedirect) {
                    $('#purchaseCompletedContainer').html('Redirecting you to paypal').show();
                    window.location.href = json.urlToRedirect;
                } else if (json.form) {
                    $('#purchaseCompletedContainer').html(json.form).show();
                } else {
                    let html = 'To complete the purchase, please send <code>' + json.amount + '</code> to <code>' + json.address + '</code>';
                    $('#purchaseCompletedContainer').html(html).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page PHP :

```
<?php
$email  = '***@****.com';

if(isset($_POST['purchase']) && isset($_POST['paymentMethod']) && isset($_POST['productId'])) {

    $paymentMethod = filter_var($_POST['paymentMethod'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $productId = filter_var($_POST['productId'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(isset($_POST['coupon']))
        $coupon = filter_var($_POST['coupon'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    else
        $coupon = '';

    $postData = [
        'product_id' => $productId,
        'purchase' => "1",
        'method' => $paymentMethod,
        'email' => $email,
        'coupon_code' => '',
        'quantity' => '1',
        'applicationID' => '10',
        'applicationSecret' => 'B346C3F5B879EBA4E6AC5A2D7ED9843DF',
        'customerIP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ];

    $ch = curl_init('<a href="https://*****.net/*****.php" rel="nofollow">https://*****.net/*****.php</a>');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($response !== false){

        die($response);

    } else {
        die(json_encode(['error' => 'Error Creating Order']));
    }
}

?>
```

Please help me.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What is the problem with your code? Please read [ask] and include all relevant information directly in your question.

Comment: Please include relevant code and errors as text, not as pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, it's was simple.

Need just to add : `javascript:` before purchases.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
}).done(function(data) {
        json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json) if (json.error) {
            $('#purchaseContainer').show();
```

Should be:

```
}).done(function(data) {
        json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json);
        if (json.error) {
            $('#purchaseContainer').show();
```

You dropped the semicolon after console.log(json).